# Accessing hdfs in java throws error

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I can access hdfs in terminal via `hdfs dfs -ls /` and I get the address and port of the cluster by `hdfs getconf -confKey fs.defaultFS` (I refer to address and port in code below).

Trying to read files on hdfs in java gave me similar errors as decribed [here](http://techidiocy.com/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-wrong-fs-expected-file/) (also discussed in this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078441/wrong-fs-expected-file-when-trying-to-read-file-from-hdfs-in-java)).
With the address I try the following in java

```
        FileSystem fs;
        BufferedReader br;
        String line;
        Path path = new Path("hdfs://<address>:<port>/somedata.txt");
        try 
        {
            /* --------------------------
             * Option 1: Gave 'Wrong FS: hdfs://..., Expected file:///' error
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
            configuration.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
            fs = FileSystem.get(configuration);
            * ---------------------------
            */

            // --------------------------
            // Option 2: Gives error stated below
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            fs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://<address>:<port>"),configuration);
            // --------------------------

            LOG.info(fs.getConf().toString());

            FSDataInputStream fsDataInputStream = fs.open(path);
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fsDataInputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            // some file processing code here.
            }
            bufferedReader .close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            fail();
        }
```

The error that option 2 gives me is

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/net/InetSocketAddress;
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:99)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1446)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:67)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1464)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:263)
at fwt.gateway.Test_Runner.checkLocationMasterindicesOnHDFS(Test_Runner.java:76)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

The fact that I can access the files from terminal is an indication for me that `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml` must be correct.

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT 1:**
The maven dependencies I use for the code below are the following

```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-alpha4</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-alpha4</version>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: Looks like you might be missing some dependencies. If you using maven or similar, can you share the hadoop imports you are doing?

Comment: thanks, is updated. why downvoted?

Comment: Probably because you don't know what a "NoSuchMethodDefError" is ... and that it typically points at a **versioning** conflict of some sort. Library A wants to call a method from library B ... but that method in B isnt there (any more). in that sense: did you do so some prior research, like searching for that exception message?

Comment: As @GhostCat mentioned, your pom shows a conflict of versions between hadoop-core and other dependencies. Should be `hadoop-common` and `3.0.0-alpha4`, I think.

Comment: This is definitely some version mismatch in dependency. Please check your build classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your POM to following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.4.2.1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Never use alpha versions as they are likely to have a bugs.

Comment: Thanks very much! Had to include the CDH 5 repository to download the jars

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in pom.xml file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have used version **2.6.0**. You can try any updated version.